# Can't use port 80 or 443 for WebSocket on XAMPP

Tags: php, websocket, port, rfc6455

I've got a Windows 7 XAMPP setup that I use for quickly testing PHP code. I have been running tests with a PHP WebSocket script I wrote recently, and it works fine on every port I've tested except ports 80 and 443. Neither 80 nor 443 will work with the `ws` or `wss` protocol. When I try either port, absolutely nothing will go through and the script will just sit there running forever.

The [official WebSocket spec (RFC 6455)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) states:

> The WebSocket Protocol attempts to address the goals of existing
> bidirectional HTTP technologies in the context of the existing HTTP
> infrastructure; as such, it is designed to work over HTTP ports 80 and
> 443 ...

And:

> By default, the WebSocket Protocol uses port 80 for regular WebSocket
> connections and port 443 for WebSocket connections tunneled over
> Transport Layer Security (TLS) [RFC2818].

And:

> The port component is OPTIONAL; the default for "ws" is port 80, while
> the default for "wss" is port 443.

So how am I supposed to get ports 80 and 443 to work?
Thanks.

---

**Edit**: Here's the first line of `netstat`:

[image: netstat]

I guess that means that I can't use port 80, right?

Comment: So, did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, this sort of issue would mean one of the following:

1. Something is already listening on those ports; port bindings cannot be shared by multiple processes.
2. You may require escalated privileges and don't have permissions to open up a listener on those ports (lower-range ports are usually reserved).

To see if it's the first issue, try using `netstat` to see what ports you have listeners for:

```
netstat -a -p TCP -o -n
```

If it's the second issue, you may have to adjust the way you're running the server so it has the proper permissions.

There may be a workaround (I haven't tried this) to enable port sharing under Windows:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733925(v=vs.110).aspx

...but the behavior may be hard to predict with that sort of setup. Another option is to set up a proxy in IIS (which I assume is what's hogging your port 80).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Indeed that confirms that port 80 is already in use by whatever PID 2576 is, so you cannot listen on that same port.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear and simple answer. That command is very handy.

Comment: I'd also add, to make this answer more appropriate to WebSockets (WS), that since port 80 and port 443 are taken by HTTP, that most WS servers run on a different port, and either have :80 and :443 forwarded by the HTTP server, or have the ports set in the client code, e.g., `socket = new WebSocket('ws://example.com:9080/');` and `socket = new WebSocket('wss://example.com:9443/);`

Answer (score 0):

This answer was last revised on November 20, 2015 at 2 PM EST.

I discovered your question because it is similar to my own during the set up process to install and configure XAMPP on my Windows 10 laptop.

*(I will explain in details what happened in my specific situation below, but before that I will put a very quick summarized answer to your question.)*

**I ran the XAMPP as administrator via right clicking it and choosing that option. 
The port problems disappeared seemingly.
Now I can open it normally by left clicking it from the pinned icon on the taskbar without specifying administrator.
The latter result occurred after restarting my computer several times in a 24 hour period.
Wish I knew precisely what changed and how it worked, but it's working perfectly now as far as I can see.**

I received some errors in the XAMPP Control Panel on November 17, 2015.
These errors said things similar to the following:

"unable to open process PID 4416"
"port 80 blocked"
"port 443 blocked"
"you are not running as an administrator"

Also, I should mention, that I am working through the steps in Chapter 2, Setting Up a Development Server, in the O'Reilly published text book 4th Edition of Learning PHP, MySQL, & JavaScript With jQuery, CSS, & HTML5 by Robin Nixon.

I also discovered that a command prompt "looking" box had opened which I did not know what to do with, and so I later closed it.

However, to get back on point, specifically it was important to me to set up with server and run it in as similar a way to the text book instructions as possible, so changing default port numbers did not appear to be a good option for me because I was not sure how alter the port number for one thing, such as the main port, might affect other ports, and other things on down the line.

I also was getting a bit confused by some other advice offered about searching, using various methods, to determine what other "things" might be interrupting the ports that my XAMMP was trying to use, akak my Apache server.

It actually appeared as though Apache was the source of the PID 4416, and that nothing was utilizing Port 80 or Port 443 at all. I also checked to see if Port 3306 was being used, because it is mentioned in the text book that it would be the default Port for MySQL, and it was not being used by anything else.

I check these PIDs by going to "Task Manager," then to "Details," then to "PID."

Then, in my Windows 10 laptop, I closed all open windows of any kind, even the XAMMP Control Panel.

Then, I typed XAMMP into the "Search Windows" bar.

When XAMMP appeared, I right clicked on it and chose to run it as Administrator.

When the Control Panel opened in this method, I received no error messages in the Control Panel for XAMMP.

However, when I pinned XAMMP to my task bar and tried to open it in a normal fashion (left-click to open) I received many errors.

But, when I right click on the pinned XAMMP icon on my task bar, and then right click again when the words XAMMP pop up, and then choose "run as administrator" it seems to be error free.

This is a work around type of solution.

I assume it might be helpful to some, but not all.

I hope it helps to shed light on similar issues.

I will be working to solve this completely.

It seems in this particular case I need to find a way to be sure the XAMMP automatically runs as adminisistrator when opened, and must require some adjustments that I simply have not discovered just yet.

I hope this is helpful to others! :)

Most of my knowledge is based in HTML5 and CSS3 and search engine optimization, and so I am working to learn more about server side, and dynamic / interactive scripting at this time.

P.S. Within 24 hours of this initial problem, after several restarts of my laptop, I was able to open XAMPP without error, in a normal fashion, by simply left clicking on the icon that I pinned to my taskbar.

I hope this is helpful as well. :)

Have a great day.

Comment: Interesting information, but you may want to move a more focused answer to the top of your post, to avoid the inevitable tl;dr

Comment: Thank you @Greg I took your advice and put a one sentence summary at the top of the post. Also included some bold and italicized focal points, and added an update. Now the long, descriptive section can be helpful to someone seeking more detail on the issue if they experience the same problem and is interested in reading the answer. I read and write a lot, and appreciate detail, however, it is helpful to highlight a quick answer for readers who might not need or desire the details. Ultimately I would hope to find someone out there that could explain these errors, but que sera sera. :) H.A.N.D.